Difficulty Extracting Value of a Key in CLOB JSON with Unknown Path
I am working with JSON data stored in a CLOB format in an Oracle database. I need to extract the value of a specific key from the JSON, but I do not know the exact path of that key. I only know the key name and want to retrieve its value regardless of its location within the JSON structure.
Example JSON
Here is an example of the JSON structure I am dealing with:
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "New York",
    "zip": "10001"
  },
  "other": {
    "info": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  }
}

I am trying to use functions like JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY to get the value of a specific key, such as the name key. However, since I do not know the exact path of this key in the JSON structure, I am having difficulty accessing it properly. I attempted to use '$..name' for searching, but I am not getting the desired result.
Oracle Version:   Oracle 19c
What is the best method to find the value of a specific key in JSON when the path is unknown?
How should I approach extracting the value of a key in an unknown path?

You can use your path in a JSON_TABLE:
SELECT j.name
FROM   table_name
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         value,
         '$..name'
         COLUMNS (
           name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
         )
       ) j

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name(value CLOB CHECK (value IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (
  '{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "New York",
    "zip": "10001"
  },
  "other": {
    "info": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  }
}'
);

Outputs:



NAME




John Doe


Jane Doe





can we write this code without inserting table and with pl/sql?

Yes:
DECLARE
  v_json CLOB := '{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "New York",
    "zip": "10001"
  },
  "other": {
    "info": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  }
}';
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT name
    FROM   JSON_TABLE(
             v_json,
             '$..name'
             COLUMNS (
               name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
             )
           )
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
John Doe
Jane Doe

But you don't need PL/SQL and can just use SQL:
SELECT name
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "New York",
    "zip": "10001"
  },
  "other": {
    "info": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  }
}',
         '$..name'
         COLUMNS (
           name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
         )
       )

Oracle 21 fiddle

can we write this code without inserting  table and  with pl/sql?
